# Enumerating Paragraphs in PDF Files

Tags: pdf

Is there a program or service available that takes PDF files and automatically enumerates paragraphs?  I have done some simple google searches and couldn't find anything readily available.

Answer (score 1):

By "enumerate paragraphs" I think you mean produce a new PDF file with numbers inserted before each paragraphs and the text reformatted to accommodate this and any other objects (e.g. images) moved around as needed and the document repaginated.

PDF was intended as a final-format form of document so it doesn't really facilitate the further manipulation of it's contents.

In particular, you can't guarantee that the internal organisation of a PDF includes any concept of paragraphs or even of words. You can't even guarantee that characters are encoded in any normal encoding - which can make it difficult to distinguish punctuation from letters.

There are software libraries for reading PDF files so you could, in principle, attempt to write such a program. This might be made to work for PDFs that are produced by one specific workflow using specific products. In general though it might work less well than converting the PDF to an image and using OCR on the image.

This sort of question ("Is there a program that ...") may be better suited to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) - but I'd be surprised if something exists that you can immediately use on random PDFs.